# Php system rating for photo gallery that allows 1 vote/day for each photo

Tags: php, jquery, gallery, photo, rating

I'm trying to develop a `Php Photo Gallery` only for my personal use and I put a `Php System Rating` using a modified script that I found on the web... all works fine except for one thing, I cannot stop users from posting several votes in the same day! I'd like that users vote the photos (several photos as well) but voting one time in the same day (one vote for each photo)... I post here the script that I have modified.

ratings.php:

```
<?php
  $rating = new ratings($_POST['widget_id']);
  isset($_POST['fetch']) ? $rating->get_ratings() : $rating->vote();
  class ratings {
    var $data_file = './ratings.data.txt';
    private $widget_id;
    private $data = array();
    function __construct($wid) {
      $this->widget_id = $wid;
      $all = file_get_contents($this->data_file);
      if ($all) {
        $this->data = unserialize($all);
      }
    }
    public function get_ratings() {
      if ($this->data[$this->widget_id]) {
        echo json_encode($this->data[$this->widget_id]);
      } else {
        $data['widget_id'] = $this->widget_id;
        $data['number_votes'] = 0;
        $data['total_points'] = 0;
        $data['dec_avg'] = 0;
        $data['whole_avg'] = 0;
        echo json_encode($data);
      }
    }
    public function vote() {
      # Get the value of the vote
      preg_match('/star_([1-5]{1})/', $_POST['clicked_on'], $match);
      $vote = $match[1];
      $ID = $this->widget_id;
      # Update the record if it exists
      if ($this->data[$ID]) {
        $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'] += 1;
        $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] += $vote;
      } else {  # Create a new one if it doesn't
        $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'] = 1;
        $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] = $vote;
      }
      $this->data[$ID]['dec_avg'] = round($this->data[$ID]['total_points'] / $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'], 1);
      $this->data[$ID]['whole_avg'] = round($this->data[$ID]['dec_avg']);
      file_put_contents($this->data_file, serialize($this->data));
      $this->get_ratings();
    }
    # ---
    # end class
  }
?>
```

ratings.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.rate_widget').each(function(i) {
    var widget = this;
    var out_data = {
    widget_id : $(widget).attr('id'),
    fetch: 1
  };
  $.post(
  'ratings/ratings.php',
  out_data,
  function(INFO) {
    $(widget).data('fsr', INFO);
    set_votes(widget);
  },
  'json'
  );
  });
  $('.ratings_stars').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
    $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
  },
  function() {
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');
    set_votes($(this).parent());
    }
  );
  $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
    var star = this;
    var widget = $(this).parent();
    var clicked_data = {
    clicked_on : $(star).attr('class'),
    widget_id : $(star).parent().attr('id')
  };
  $.post(
  'ratings/ratings.php',
  clicked_data,
  function(INFO) {
  widget.data('fsr', INFO);
  set_votes(widget);
  },
  'json'
  ); 
  });
});
function set_votes(widget) {
  var avg = $(widget).data('fsr').whole_avg;
  var votes = $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes;
  var exact = $(widget).data('fsr').dec_avg;
  window.console && console.log('and now in set_votes, it thinks the fsr is ' + $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes);
  $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
  $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
  $(widget).find('.total_votes').text( votes + ' votes (' + exact + ' rating)' );
}
```

I tried to implement IP mechanism in ratings.php as below without lucky

```
<?php
  $rating = new ratings($_POST['widget_id']);
  isset($_POST['fetch']) ? $rating->get_ratings() : $rating->vote();
  class ratings {
    var $data_file = './ratings.data.txt';
    private $widget_id;
    private $data = array();
    function __construct($wid) {
      $this->widget_id = $wid;
      $all = file_get_contents($this->data_file);
      if ($all) {
        $this->data = unserialize($all);
      }
    }
    public function get_ratings() {
      if ($this->data[$this->widget_id]) {
        echo json_encode($this->data[$this->widget_id]);
      } else {
        $data['widget_id'] = $this->widget_id;
        $data['number_votes'] = 0;
        $data['total_points'] = 0;
        $data['dec_avg'] = 0;
        $data['whole_avg'] = 0;
        echo json_encode($data);
      }
    }
    public function vote() {
      # Get the value of the vote
      preg_match('/star_([1-5]{1})/', $_POST['clicked_on'], $match);
      $vote = $match[1];
      $ID = $this->widget_id;
      # Update the record if it exists
      if ($this->data[$ID]) {
        $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'] += 1;
        $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] += $vote;
        $this->data[$ID]['remote_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      } else {  # Create a new one if it doesn't
        $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'] = 1;
        $this->data[$ID]['total_points'] = $vote;
        $this->data[$ID]['remote_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      }
      if ($this->data[$ID]['remote_ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {
        $this->data[$ID]['dec_avg'] = round($this->data[$ID]['total_points'] / $this->data[$ID]['number_votes'], 1);
        $this->data[$ID]['whole_avg'] = round($this->data[$ID]['dec_avg']);
        file_put_contents($this->data_file, serialize($this->data));
        $this->get_ratings();
      }
    }
    # ---
    # end class
  }
?>
```

[image: my web gallery]

Comment: I don;t see in your code examples where you have even tried to limit the number of posts per image per day. Have you made an attempt to do this at all?  If so, what SPECIFIC problem did you run into? As your question stands right now, it sounds like you are basically looking for someone to tell you how to do this, which makes this question way too broad for SO since there are a number of ways to go about this.

Comment: I posted an example... but is not working...

Comment: @MikeBrant I posted yesterday an example showing what I'd like to do... but my simple example don't work... I try to be more exact, my example simple do not allow me to vote but I should  be able to give almost one vote while nothing...if ($this->data[$ID]['remote_ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) {

Comment: Since google drive has some problem in sharing the same file with a lot of persons I decided to put on DropBox a zipped file containing all need for testing my photo gallery with rating... so you can test in local with lamp or wamp... I removed photos for sharing light the pizzed file... I removed the admin/login/upload panel of my photo gallery since aren't important for testing purpose... thanks... if you want test in localhost please put some photos inside the folder "gallery" inside the zipped file... I removed highslide.js too so the zipped file is very very small :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to notify in a data table who vote and which day.

For example : Toto vote on 2014-07-04, so he can't vote twice today.

In data table user you add a colum date to notify the last day of vote.

You can use cookies but it's very very ugly !

Comment: Cookies can be deleted. Timestamp + IP is the way.

Comment: @Traian Tatic said the solution in that case ;)
But it's easiest to cheat I think.

Comment: Then I hope solving asap :)

Comment: I cannot know who rates my photos since the system rating is anonymous... there is no need to login for voting... the easiest way for voting is without doing login... so perfect strangers can vote my photos...